Can I send a message to teams' channel via curl and @someone at the same time?
My leadership would like me to be able to @ people in the teams channel after a jenkins build has finished who should be concerned about the results of the build, such as the culprits who caused the build to go wrong. So far I've implemented a monitoring script that sends an email or message to teams, and I was wondering if I could go to @ someone and have that person notice the message? If so, can you tell me how to do this using curl?
I've tried using @ in the notification message, but it doesn't work.

Try <at>username</at> instead of @username. At least for GraphQL that's how mentions are done.

Tried it, but since I can only get the email address from jenkins, it seems that teams doesn't support looking up by email, it just displays it as a string. So this method fails. But I noticed that because I use outlook proxy when sending emails, the teams emails show my id in the from section. Is there any way to extend this conversion to other users as well?

Not knowing the username is a separate issue. If your original question is answered then mark it accordingly and ask a new question.
